# How to add items in JCombobox inside Jinternalframe?

Tags: java, arduino

I have a project in arduino that i interface with java. The arduino is connected to the computer via usb cable , I use the serial communication to be able to connect. I want to scan the port on where the arduino is connected and populate the drop down box using this code:

```
     SerialPort[] portNames = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    for(int i=0; i < portNames.length; i++){
     portList.addItem(portNames[i].getSystemPortName());
```

[The JInternalFrame Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juk50.png) 
The JComboBox is inside JInternalFrame the code generated by netbeans is :

```
public class ConnectToArduino extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

/** Creates new form ConnectToArduino */
public ConnectToArduino() {
    initComponents();
    portScan();



}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setIconifiable(true);
    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(automatedwateringandmonitoringsystem.AutomatedWateringandMonitoringSystemApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(ConnectToArduino.class);
    setTitle(resourceMap.getString("Form.title")); // NOI18N
    setName("Form"); // NOI18N

    jPanel1.setName("jPanel1"); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("jLabel1.font")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("jLabel1.icon")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel1.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setName("jLabel1"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setName("jPanel2"); // NOI18N

    jLabel2.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("jLabel2.font")); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel2.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setName("jLabel2"); // NOI18N

    jComboBox1.setName("jComboBox1"); // NOI18N

    jButton1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jButton1.text")); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setName("jButton1"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
// End of variables declaration
```

When I try this code below I get and Error

```
 jComboBox1<String> portlist = new jComboBox1<Sting>();
```

Thanks For Reading :D GoodBless All

Comment: is there a character missing in the word `Sting`  ?

Comment: yeah but I still got error . it says cannot find symbol

Comment: Try:  `jComboBox1<String> portlist = new jComboBox1<>();`. I believe that ComboBoxes are now generic class.

Comment: Still got an error :( @Thrasher

Comment: Still got an error :( @Thrasher